# Syntax error in expression

Tags: bash

It's written syntax error in expression (error token is "tmp") in lines 5 and 11, which both are "for" lines, my tmp file was created 2 lines ago and doesn't even appear in those lines, if you could help
Thanks

```
function coursesToFind {
local courseToSearch=$1
grep $1 courses.list > tmp
local linesNumber=$(wc -l tmp | cut -f1)
for((i = 0; i<$linesNumber; i++)); do
local arrToSearchIn=$(grep $courseToSearch courses.list | head -n+1 |  tail -1)
if (($arrToSearchIn==$courseToSearch)) ; then
break
fi
done
for((i=$linesNumber; i>2 ;i--)); do
if (($arrToSearchIn[i]==*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9])) ; then
coursesArray[n]=$(arr[i])
n++
coursesToFind $(arr[i])
fi
done
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the error message? And please format your code so it is more readable using block indentation.

Comment: Learn to use http://shellcheck.net **before** you post your code here ;-) . When you use shellcheck, you need to include a proper "she-bang" line as the first line, usually `#!/bin/bash` . Good luck.

Comment: You might want to check out https://www.shellcheck.net/ ; note that your script has more than a single mistake if I'm not mistaken, and I see nothing about that `tmp` token. First thing I'd fix is the regex match which should be of the following form : `if [[ "value"~=regex ]]`

Comment: @Aaron Needs spaces and should be `=~`.

Comment: Also, read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), which discusses the correct way to iterate over the output of a command.

Comment: Here is the exact error message : 
./preCourses: line 5: ((: i<2 tmp: syntax error in expression (error token is "tmp")
./preCourses: line 11: ((: i=2 tmp: syntax error in expression (error token is "tmp")

Comment: Every StackOverflow question should ideally revolve around *one* error, with everything unrelated to that specific error removed/factored out (see the docs on building a [mcve]). Having a bunch of unrelated ones stuffed into the same question makes this overbroad -- if you ask a question with *one* problem and we have a duplicate, we can close it as a dupe; if you ask a single question with *five* and four are dupes, then it's just "too broad" -- we can't close four out of five separate pieces of the question as dupes and answer the fifth.

Comment: ...so, if your question is only about the line-5 error message, the question should have *the shortest possible code* that generates that specific error when run on its own, with everything unrelated removed.

Comment: See in particular the *"How to turn a bad script into a good question"* section of [the StackOverflow bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: @BenjaminW. woops

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a closer look at what's happening here:

> ```
> local courseToSearch=$1
> grep $1 courses.list > tmp
> local linesNumber=$(wc -l tmp | cut -f1)
> for((i = 0; i<$linesNumber; i++)); do
> local arrToSearchIn=$(grep $courseToSearch courses.list | head -n+1 |  tail -1)
> ```

An error is reported on line 5, `for((i = 0; i<$linesNumber; i++)); do`,
the message is something like:

> ```
> script.sh: line 5: ((: i<       6 tmp: syntax error in expression (error token i
> ```

What is the `i<      6 tmp` there?
Does it look familiar?
It comes from the condition `i<$linesNumber` in the code.
The value of `$linesNumber` is highly suspicious.
If you add an `echo $linesNumber` just before the `for` loop,
you would see something like this:

```
      6 tmp
```

The number 6 depends on the example input, but this detail doesn't matter.
What matters is that the value of `$linesNumber` is not a number.

This is easy to fix, by improving the lines that are responsible for this value. Let's go over this piece step by step:

> ```
> local courseToSearch=$1
> grep $1 courses.list > tmp
> local linesNumber=$(wc -l tmp | cut -f1)
> ```

It's very good that you assigned the value of `$1` to a variable with a descriptive name `courseToSearch`.
But then why don't you use it in the `grep`?

Second, the `grep $1 courses.list` is unsafe,
as it will break if the function parameter contains unsafe characters.
You can fix that by double-quoting.

Next, do you really need a temporary file `tmp`?
Not really.
In fact this part is one of the main sources of your problems.
The problem is that `tmp` contains a number and a filename,
and the `cut -f1` is not effective at removing it.
If you don't use a temporary file,
but pipe the output of `grep` directly,
there will be no output file to worry about.

Putting the above tips together:

```
local courseToSearch=$1
local linesNumber=$(grep "$courseToSearch" courses.list | wc -l)
```

This will fix the loop.

But let's go a bit further.
What's going on here:

> ```
> local arrToSearchIn=$(grep $courseToSearch courses.list | head -n+1 |  tail -1)
> ```

In particular, what does the `head -n+1 |  tail -1`?
Take the first line of the input,
and then take the last line of that?
The `tail` doesn't make sense when there is already just one line.
Write like this:

```
local arrToSearchIn=$(grep "$courseToSearch" courses.list | head -n 1)
```

And there are probably many more problems in the rest of the code.

Follow the same kind of logic as I explained above.
Find the purpose of every single bit of code.
Every single bit must have a purpose, and you must understand that purpose.
If you don't understand something,
find it in the documentation.
If you still don't understand it,
then remove it, and observe what difference it makes.
Trim the script down to its simplest possible form,
such that you can understand.
Remove features if necessary.
Add back features gradually,
observing the difference that each step makes, and learn from it.
Good luck!

Comment: @shellter no worries, your comment made me find a crucial typo around there ;-)